# Change the path to take the images

Tags: android, image, assets

I´m trying to do a HorizontalScrollview with images taking from assets folder. I am working with a example that takes the images from the External Storage and I don´t know what do I have to change the path to assets folder.

```java
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myGallery = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mygallery);

    String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
      .getExternalStorageDirectory()
      .getAbsolutePath();

    String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/test/";

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), targetPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

    File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
    for (File file : files){
         myGallery.addView(insertPhoto(file.getAbsolutePath()));
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the assets is fairly simple:

Single photo:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
InputStream is = assetManager.open("photo.jpeg");
```

List of photos:

```
AssetManager  assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
String[] files =  assetManager.list("");
for(String f: files){
    File photo = new File(f); //or
    InputStream is = assetManager.open(f);
    //do something with the photo

}
```